# Flutter iterate through Stream<List<DocumentSnapshot<Object?>>>

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have an object of type

```
Stream<List<DocumentSnapshot<Object?>>>
```

That is returned from my database. I'm using it in a method that sends data and such so I don't believe I can use a stream builder with it to iterate over it.

I want to be able to loop through each one and use an if statement so I can check data on each document snapshot in the list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked it out I sumply just had to do

```
users.listen((List<DocumentSnapshot> documentList) {
    // doSomething()
    documentList.forEach((DocumentSnapshot document) {
      //do code in here
    }
}
```